# Is kernel/sched.c/context_switch() guaranteed to be invoked every time a process is switched in?

Tags: c, linux, process, scheduler, context-switch

I want to alter the Linux kernel so that every time the current PID changes - i.e., a new process is switched in - some diagnostic code is executed (detailed explanation below, if curious). I did some digging around, and it seems that every time the scheduler chooses a new process, the function `context_switch()` is called, which makes sense (this is just from a cursory analysis of `sched.c/schedule()` ).

The problem is, the Linux scheduler is basically black magic to me right now, so I'd like to know if that assumption is correct. Is it guaranteed that, every time a new process is selected to get some time on the CPU, the context_switch() function is called? Or are there other places in the kernel source where scheduling could be handled in other situations? (Or am I totally misunderstanding all this?)

To give some context, I'm working with the MARSS x86 simulator trying to do some instrumentation and measurement of certain programs. The problem is that my instrumentation needs to know which executing process certain code events correspond to, in order to avoid misinterpreting the data. The idea is to use some built-in message passing systems in MARSS to pass the PID of the new process on every context switch, so it always knows what PID is currently in execution. If anyone can think of a simpler way to accomplish that, that would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

The `schedule()` will call `context_switch()` which is responsible for switching from one task to another when the new process has been selected by `schedule()`.

`context_switch()` basically does two things. It calls `switch_mm()` and `switch_to()`.

`switch_mm()` - switch to the virtual memory mapping for the new process

`switch_to()` - switch the processor state from the previous process to the new process (save/restore registers, stack info and other architecture specific things)

As for your approach, I guess it's fine. It's important to keep things nice and clean when working with the kernel, and try to keep it relatively easy until you gain more knowledge.